How does plotly does the calculations in the dataframe for sunburst diagram
I am trying to display a sunburst plot using plotly from a dataframe. The plot looks correct and the % dsplayed also but the amount of each sector in the center is wrong. I dont understand how is this calculated in the background.
fig = px.sunburst(df,
                  path=['status', 'department'],
                  values='PCT',
                  title='test|',
                  color='amount',
                  hover_data=['ISO'],
                  color_continuous_scale='RdBu',
                  color_continuous_midpoint=np.average(df['PCT'],  weights=df['amount']),
                  width=800,
                  height=800
                 )
fig.update_layout(title = {
    'y':0.95, # new
    'x':0.5,
    'xanchor': 'center',
    'yanchor': 'top' # new
    },
                  coloraxis_colorbar_x=1.2,
                  coloraxis_colorbar_y=0.5,
                  coloraxis_colorbar=dict(title="test")
                 )
fig.update_coloraxes(colorbar_len=0.4, colorbar_showticklabels=True, cmin=0, cmax=100)
fig.update_traces(texttemplate = '%{label}<br>%{value:.1%}')
fig.show()



